# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor seleccionado de un combobox de WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy llenado los valores de un combobox de WPF mediante un procedimiento almacenado que almacena valores en un dataTable, el cual convierto a tipo **IListSource** para pasarle los valores y el combobox obtiene los valores deseados

```
        DataTable dataTable = readGeneralData.GetDataTable("[sysfox].[List_DatosFox]");

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lstEmpresas.Items.Clear();

            var items = (dataTable as IListSource).GetList(); //  Lista de empresas

            lstEmpresas.ItemsSource         =   items;
            lstEmpresas.DisplayMemberPath   =   "NombreLegal";
            lstEmpresas.SelectedValuePath   =   "IdDatosFox";
            lstEmpresas.SelectedIndex       =   0;
        }
```

el punto está en que quiero retornar el valor seleccionado del combobox, pero no puedo hacerlo, intenté con:

```
ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem   =   (ComboBoxItem)lstEmpresas.SelectedItem;
string valorDeseado = comboBoxItem.Content.ToString(); // Funciona sólo con datos estáticos
```

XAML:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="lstEmpresas"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Sin empresa</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Y funciona bien para datos estáticos de pruebas, pero con los valores obtenidos con **IListSource** tiene un conflicto de conversión lo cual imposibilita obtener el valor seleccionado, ¿Cómo podría obtener el valor seleccionado?, está claro que el contenido de la selección y el (VALUE) valor seleccionado son distintos, estoy abierto a cualquier sugerencia para cambiar la lógica de obtención de datos.

Comment: SelectedItem no es un string?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, no es string es de tipo **System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: YourItem**, agradecería mucho que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: que error te tira con la Ilist?

Comment: Este: System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.'

Comment: entonces los items del combo son del tipo DataRowView. trata de usar un var, en lugar del tipo especifico, deja que haga la conversion el compilador y aplicale tostring a eso a ver que pasa

Comment: Es que justo la finalidad de convertirlo explicitamente a ComboBoxItem **.. (ComboBoxItem)lstEmpresas.SelectedItem;** es obtener el método **Content** y así obtener el resultado en **comboBoxItem.Content.ToString();**,  ya intenté así y el resultado es el mismo **var comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)lstEmpresas.SelectedItem;**

Comment: Si el contenido que estas buscando, es un string, que importa de que objeto viene? vos solo queres el testo que sale en combo no? probaste con selectedText?

Comment: Me parece que no existe **selectedText** en WPF, y bueno lo que busco es el Value, porque del NombreLegal de la empresa que se seleccione me interesa su ID.

Comment: Ah ok.. listo.. ahi es otra cosa... dejame ver si encuentro algo

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi ;)

Comment: No es SelectedValue lo que buscas?

Comment: Intenté con eso y me salió esto **System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Sin empresa** hehehe sorprendente lo acabo de probar con los datos de base de datos y si da el resultado que busco. Mil gracias @gbianchi

Comment: Fijate en la respuesta que te dieron abajo a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Si lo probaré nunca esta demás obtener mas formas de realizar las cosas. gracias ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El ItemSource del codigo que muestras es una coleccion de DataRowView, para esto debes castearlo:

```
var row = lstEmpresas.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
//Para acceder a los valores por ejemplo
var id = row["IdDatosFox"];
var nombreLegal = row["NombreLegal"];
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó gracias ;).